# Does "track changes" exist in Excel 2003?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

Do we have Track changes in Excel 2003?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Excel 2003 has Track Changes feature. It's in `Tools > Track Changes`.

For more details, see [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_2020062_track-changes-excel.html) and [this](http://www.referpages.com/reference/computing/34-wp/116-track.html) pages.

Comment: can we do this thru VBA?

Comment: I guess yes. Take a look at this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177811%28office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: This [page](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/track-changes.htm) seems quite helpful as well.